# Reset dropzone when windows get refresh or closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have dropzone file and button to save, on dropzone if i uploadfile into dropzone is will automactly move to my folder, and when i press button save, that file name it will save on mysql data. Now the problem is, i want my file get reset dropzone when i refresh page or closed page before i pres button save? Is that impposible??
Here my code!!

On HTML

```
<div class="dropzone form-control input-sm" action="<?php echo SERVER_NAME; ?>upload/file" id="dropZone">
                            <div class="fallback" >
                                <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

On Jquery

```
Dropzone.options.dropZone = {
            //options here
            maxFilesize: 1,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            removedfile: function(file) {
                var name = file.name;        
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: host+'upload/unfile',
                    data: "id="+name,
                    dataType: 'html'
                });
                var _ref;
                return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;   

                //console.log();
            }

        }
```

on contorler

```
public function file(){
            if (!empty($_FILES)) {
                $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
                $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
                $targetPath = './public/uploads/';
                $targetFile = $targetPath . $fileName ;

                //var_dump($_FILES);
                move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
            }
        }

        public function unfile() {
            $fileName = $_POST["id"];
            //var_dump($fileName);
            $targetPath = './public/uploads/';
            $targetFile = $targetPath . $fileName ;
            unlink($targetFile);

        }
```

NOTE :I need when refresh/closed page the file uploaded but not save mysql will be remove on my folder.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i found it, i use this code, and prefectly remove my file :)

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
              return 'Are you sure you want to leave? Warning!!! Data is still progress will not be saved';
        });

        $(window).on('unload', function(){
                var file = $('.dropzone .dz-preview').children().find('.dz-filename').find('span').html();                    
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: host+'upload/unfile',
                    data: "id="+file,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    async : false
                });
                //alert('Your Out!!');
        });
```

Not if someone have problem like i am with dropzone u must use `async : false` that so important!!!